# Consume ONLY latest message

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I'm programming a Kafka Consumer in an ASP.NET web application, all seems good but every time I run the consumer, it consumes all messages in the topic.

Here the Consumer config.

```
ConsumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            GroupId = _config["KafkaConfig:GroupId"],
            BootstrapServers = _config["KafkaConfig:BootstrapServer"],
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
        };
```

I'm using Confluent Kafka Client for .NET

Comment: A few questions come to mind. Is Consumer auto commits disabled? Is the GroupId changing? How long is the gap between running the Consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not into web application but on ts for example you can set a fromBeginning flag.

```
await consumer.subscribe({topic: 'test-topic', fromBeginning: false});
```

this makes the consumer only get the messages from the point on you subscripe.

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you always want the very last message at any time your app starts, then Kafka is not the correct tool.

You can `Seek()` your consumer to the very end, grab that offset, then `Seek(N-1)`, **but** there may be producers that have sent *new records* between those seek calls.

If you must use Kafka, then will want to use something like ksqlDB / Kafka Streams or Kafka Connect to create a KTable or Database that stores latest values *per key* that you can query remotely.